# @(at) operator at Python, how to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to run a python code. This code have an '@' ( at) operator. I never saw it before, and Google returns no hits.

```
init = model.potentials[key].init_weights(model)
if init.ndim==2:
    U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(init, False)
    init = U@Vt
```

It says the following error:

```
init = U@Vt
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using Python 2.7 to compile it. Do anyone know about this operator ?

Comment: Looks like a misprint in this case

Answer (score 11):

The `@` operator was proposed in [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) and adopted into Python 3.5.  You can't use it because you are using an older branch of Python.  It is used to multiply matrixes (usually, but you can actually make `@` do anything).  You can use `numpy.dot()` instead if you are working with NumPy arrays, like this:

```
init = model.potentials[key].init_weights(model)
if init.ndim==2:
    U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(init, False)
    init = np.dot(U, Vt)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `@` is `np.matmul`, not `np.dot`

Comment: `np.matmul` itself is new.  In this 2d context `np.dot` is equivalent.  It describes `dot` as, `alternative matrix product with different broadcasting rules`.

Comment: Here is a link to documentation on np.matmul: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html